# Redirect in an Admin page

Tags: admin, redirect

I have a menu item I created called 'View Certificates' and a sub menu item called 'Add Certificates'.  The Add Certificates page is just a file upload page.  After the file uploads successfully, I want it to redirect back to the 'View Certificates' page.

All my code is in the functions.php file.  How do I go about doing this redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
<?php 
$url='something.com';
wp_redirect($url); 
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: im getting errors about not modifying the headers

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-admin/admin-header.php:34) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934

Comment: wp_redirect acts the same as "php header( 'Location:" You can not output any html before you run it. If you ar ein functions.php you should be able to do it. If you form use javascript maybe you can add a callback and do a javscript location.replace="yoursite.com"

Answer (score 0):

How about standard `header( 'Location: http://ViewCertificatesPage' );`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

`wp_redirect` is a function which helps you to redirect http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

& you can run it in conditions with http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags